# How to change colors for a button in react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I know that changing colors is very difficult in react-bootstrap, but I would like to have my button with a color that isn't a primary color. How can I do this in JS/SCSS?

Answer (score 10):

```js
const App = () => (
  <div className="content">
    <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="primary">Default Button</ReactBootstrap.Button>
    <ReactBootstrap.Button bsClass="custom-btn">Custom Button</ReactBootstrap.Button>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.custom-btn {
  background: #fff;
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.32.1/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="react"></div>
```

To add the specific styling to `react-bootstrap` `<Button />` component, simply use `bsClass` property

Taken from [the official docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/theming/

for buttons specifically, you can add variant='custom' attribute in Button component and in css file, you can customize your button like this:

```css
.btn-custom {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In a pinch, I was able to use inline-style for some simple styling of buttons in ReactStrap.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';

const PageButtons = (props) => {

return (

        <div>
        {!props.data.previous ? null : <Button style={{color:"#00005c", margin: "5%", boxShadow: "5px 5px 3px rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.62)"}} outline onClick={props.handlePrevious}>Previous</Button>}
        {!props.data.next ? null : <Button style={{ color:"#00005c", margin: "5%", boxShadow: "5px 5px 3px rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.62)"}} outline onClick={props.handleNext}>Next</Button>}
        </div>

      );
    }

    export default PageButtons;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add CSS in Css File or if you are using pcss

following css

```
.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #2E4C80;
    background-color: cutom-color;
    border-color: #2E4C80;
    border-color: cutom-cor;
}
```

it will automatically override defaults

Answer (score 1):

You can use this "**Theming and Customizing styles**" tutorial from react-bootstrap.

Based on the version of react-bootstrap you have installed you can choose either of these links:

https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/getting-started/theming/

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/getting-started/theming.

If this link changes in the future then my suggestion is to check the "Theming" page of the react-bootstrap website because it answers this question correctly.

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO. See [answer].

Comment: This link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Override with `!important`:

App.css

```
.button {
  background-color: #370344 !important;
}
```

component

```
<Button className="button">Submit</Button>
```

Comment: I would call this an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with react conditional properties

```
<button
  className={
    selectedOffer?._id == offer._id
      ? "btn btn-danger rounded-0 mx-1"
      : "btn btn-outline-danger rounded-0 mx-1 bg-white"
  }
  style={
    selectedOffer?._id == offer._id
      ? { backgroundColor: "#FA0105" }
      : { borderColor: "#FA0105" }
  }
  onClick={() => setSelectedOffer(offer)}
>
  {offer.slug}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out—if you use SCSS, here's a solution to modify the button and the (I'm assuming it'll be a link) text it contains. As others have mentioned above, it's critical that you include the `'!important'` rule on each line of style. While almost all examples I've come across online have named the custom button class `'custom-btn'`, you can actually just name it whatever you want.

The example below creates a Bootstrap button with a custom yellow background color, custom margin and border specifications, and white font color for the enclosed link inside the button.

### JSX

```
<Button className="any-class-name-you-want">
    <a href="your-link">your-text</a>
</Button
```

### SCSS

```scss
.any-class-name-you-want {
  background-color: #fcb426 !important;
  margin: 10px 50px !important;
  border: 1px solid #fff !important;

  a {
    color: white !important; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that want to change the color of an active/clicked button in react-bootstrap, you have to override the buttons default scss calls. So, for example if you wanted to change all primary buttons when active/clicked it would look something like this:

```
index.css

.btn-primary:active {
  --bs-btn-active-bg:#ff79c6;
  --bs-btn-active-border-color: #ff79c6;
  --bs-btn-active-color: #44475a;
}
```